# Execute shell scripts based on value of key pressed

Tags: python, shell, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I execute different shell scripts (tes1.sh, test2.sh, ..) based on different keyboard events using python.

If user press `"1"` execute `test1.sh` if `"2"` `test2.sh` and etc.

I got pressed key using "raw-input" and based on the input value I have called "test1.sh" or "test2.sh" using subprocess.call.

How can I stop running current shell script and run new one if different key is pressed.

Comment: Your question hides multiple other questions. Which one did you actually want answered? "How do I run a shell script from Python?", "How do I get user input from the keyboard (prompt/response style)?", "How do I detect key presses while doing something else? (as in while running a game)". What have you actually tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subprocess.call (according to my knowledge of python docs) is not good idea here because you want to kill (stop) that process after key press... It's better to use subprocess.Popen here, because it doesn't blocks interaction with process while it's running. Subprocess.call waits for program to complete and then returns a code representing the process exit status. To call and kill process, you can do something like this:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('script.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                   shell=False, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

I hope this helps you, if you don't understand something, feel free to ask in comments...

P.S. If you don't know how to check for key press take a look at this part of docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to recommend `shell=True`? I don't see how it's useful here.

Comment: @tripleee Nope, you are correct, I edited my answer, it's useless here. Thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subprocess.call` and `raw_input()` for python2 and `input` in python3:

```
import subprocess
num=raw_input('print the number : ')

if num=='1' :
   subprocess.call('test1.sh')
elif num == '2':
   subprocess.call('test2.sh')
```